# How to take input of full line from mysql in html php

Tags: php, html, mysql

My database field contains a sentence as a varchar suppose "Hello I am online" I want to show that field as a input placeholder. I write the following code but it shows only "Hello". but if I place echo command then if shows the full sentence. I think i am making some silly mistakes but could not find what is that. please help.

```
<?php
  $servername = "localhost:3306";
  $username = "admin";
  $password = "pass";
  $dbname = "test_db";

  // Create connection
  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

  // Check connection
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Database Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  }

  $sql = "select * from test_table";

  $sqldata = $conn->query($sql);
  if(! $sqldata)
  {
    die ("error opening database");
  }    
?>
<form  method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
<div class="form_layout">
    <?php while( $row = $sqldata->fetch_assoc()) : ?>
      <div >
        <label> Name :</label>
        <input type="text" id="iname" name="institutename" placeholder=<?php echo $row['msg']; ?>>
        <?php echo $row['msg']; ?>
      </div>
    <?php endwhile ?>
</div>
</form>
```

it showing "hello" in the input section but"Hello I am online" on the next echo command.

Comment: Multiword placeholders should be surrounded by quotes.

Comment: `</form` < Just want to make sure that you did close that off properly, or was that just a bad paste?

Comment: it just a typing mistake. I closed the form properly.@FunkFortyNiner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistakes is here

```
placeholder=<?php echo $row['msg']; ?>
```

Replace this

```
placeholder="<?php echo $row['msg']; ?>"
```